# onclick getting the correct data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an index view of a table called tasks.  On each row I want the user to be able to click on Edit or Add Attach (add an attachment).

This is the code:

```
  <% @workorder.tasks.each do |task| %>
  <tr>
        <td><%= task.position %></td>
        <td><strong><%= link_to task.taskname, task_path(task) %></strong></td>
        <td>
          <a rel="popover" data-content="<%= task.longdesc %>" data-original-title="Description:"><img src='/images/find.ico' width='20' height='20'></a>
        </td>
        <td><%= task.employee.try(:employee_full_name) %></td>
        <td><%= task.taskstatus.try(:statuscode) %></td>
        <td><%= task.attachments.count %></td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="answer" data-type="select" data-pk="1" data-resource="task" data-source="/ratings" data-name="rating_id" data-url="/tasks/<%= task.id %>" data-original-title="Select Rating">
            <% if task.rating_id != nil %>
                <%= textarea_format(task.rating.ratingname) %>
            <% end %>
          </a>
        </td>
        <% if current_user.admin == true %>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task), :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-success' %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Add Attach', new_attachment_path, :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-primary', :onclick =>  flash[:task_id] = task.id %></td>
        <% end %>
  </tr>
```

The Add Attach links to a page for adding the attachment. In order to have it properly attach to the specific task, I use flash to carry forward the task.id.

But, the onclick is always passing the last task.id instead of each button containing the task.id for that row.

Any idea how I could accomplish this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think your 'Add Attach' link would look like:

```
  <td>
    <%= link_to 'Add Attach', 
        new_attachment_path(task.id),
       :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-primary'
    %> 
  </td>
```

This assumes you have a route entry that looks something like:

```
match "tasks/:id/add_attach" => "tasks#add_attach" , :as=>"new_attachment"
```

Then in your tasks_controller.rb:

```
def add_attach
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  # I don't know what goes here,  not enough code posted
  @task.save
end
```